# Dynamically search SQL table and display on HTML using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I have a form where I want the user to select an Organization from a SQL table and when the form is submitted, the ID of the selected organization should be saved to a different table. I researched online and on SO, and this is what I have now. And it does not work. What's wrong? 
Newbrand.php:

```
<form action="newbrand.php" method="post">

        Brand Name: <input type="text" name="bname" /><br><br>
        Ogranization: <input type="text" name="searchbar" id="searchbar"><br><br>
        <script>
        $("#searchbar").keyup(function(){
        var searchTerm = $(this).val();

        $.post('search.php', { search_term: searchTerm}, function(data){

            $(".searchResults").html(data);
            $("#searchUl").css("display", "block");
            });
        });
        </script>
        Organization ID: <input type="hidden" name="gid" value="" /><br><br>
        Gallery ID: <input type="text" name="gid" /><br><br>
</form>
```

Search.php:

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);

$search_term = sanitize(htmlentities($_POST['search_term']));

if (!empty($search_term)){

$search = "(SELECT `Organization_Name` FROM `organizations_info` WHERE `Organization_Name` LIKE '%$search_term%'  LIMIT 0, 5) ";
$query = mysqli_query($link, $search);
$result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    #$user_id = $row['user_id'];
    #$username = $row['username'];
    $orgname = $row['Organization_Name'];
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($query);



    if ($check != 0){
        echo "<a style='text-decoration: none; color: black;' href='newbrand.php?band=$orgname'><li class='searchResults'>" . ucfirst($orgname) . "</li></a>";
    } else {
        echo "<li class='searchResults'>No Results Found</li>";
    }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your query. It's not passing the value of `$search_term`, but rather passing it as a string. You may want to use prepared statements and bind the parameter first:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT `Organization_Name` FROM `organizations_info` WHERE `Organization_Name` LIKE ? LIMIT 0, 5");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", "%{$search_term}%");

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $organizaton_name);

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

}
```

Reference: [mysqli SELECT With Prepared Statements](http://markonphp.com/mysqli-select-prepared-statements/)

Comment: Still nothing shows up when I type in the text field

Comment: Are you sure `$search_term` has a value?

Comment: I am not sure, how do I check it? Sorry, I'm new to all this, so please bear with me

Comment: I'm also new with PHP. Try echoing it before the call to `sanitize`.

Comment: I commented out the whole sanitize thing and just declared `$search_term = $_POST['search_term'];`. And echoed it there (in search.php). But when I type in `newbrand.php`, nothing happens. Is there something wrong with the js? Are the names called in it all correct?

Answer (score 0):

I searched the web for this function and found this. I copyed your source and got it working like this:

$search = "(SELECT `Organization_Name` FROM `organizations_info` WHERE `Organization_Name` LIKE '%". $search_term . "%'  LIMIT 0, 5) ";

As you can see I changed the '%". $search_term . "%' , because you can't just place strings in sql query that is between "", you have to cut it in pieces, hope you understand now. I don't go on this site often, so it would be cool if you send me an mail if it fixed the problem to sceptdeckheroes@gmail.com, would like to hear from you, good luck.

Comment: Your syntax is undoubtedly better, but "WHERE `Organizatiions_Name` LIKE '$search_term%' " **will** work, because % is a non-word character. To avoid ambiguity it should have been written "... LIKE '%{$search_term}%'...", but it wasn't a problem.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that, I encountered promblems with the code as was written, after I changed it to the version with the ". . " the problems disapeared, so I thought that was the problem, but I'm no expert. Maybe I did something else that made the problem disapear, anyway my code works for as far as I know. I'm, confused